# Elements of array '...' have incomplete type. Libopencm3

Tags: c, arm, stm32

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь запустить пример к библиотеке libopecm3 под stm32.

Имеется структура данного вида:

```
struct usb_config_descriptor {
    uint8_t bLength;
    uint8_t bDescriptorType;
    uint16_t wTotalLength;
    uint8_t bNumInterfaces;
    uint8_t bConfigurationValue;
    uint8_t iConfiguration;
    uint8_t bmAttributes;
    uint8_t bMaxPower;

    /* Descriptor ends here.  The following are used internally: */
    const struct usb_interface {
        uint8_t *cur_altsetting;
        uint8_t num_altsetting;
        const struct usb_iface_assoc_descriptor *iface_assoc;
        const struct usb_interface_descriptor *altsetting;
    } *interface;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

Её экземпляр создаётся так:

```
const struct usb_interface ifaces[] = {  
  {
    .num_altsetting = 1,
    .altsetting = &iface,
  }
};

const struct usb_config_descriptor config = {
    .bLength = USB_DT_CONFIGURATION_SIZE,
    .bDescriptorType = USB_DT_CONFIGURATION,
    .wTotalLength = 0,
    .bNumInterfaces = 1,
    .bConfigurationValue = 1,
    .iConfiguration = 0,
    .bmAttributes = 0x80,
    .bMaxPower = 0x32,

    .interface = ifaces,
};
```

Как C код, этот участок отлично компилируется, а как C++ код - 
получается ошибка

> "elements of array 'const usb_interface ifaces []' have incomplete type".

Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: Может быть, вы не подключили header, в котором у вас определяется структура?

Comment: @NO2B Не могли бы вы пояснить, почему вы считаете, что этот код должен компилироваться в C++, если в C++ отсутствуют именованные инициализаторы?

Answer (score 3):

Данная конструкция

```
const struct usb_interface ifaces[] = {  
  {
    .num_altsetting = 1,
    .altsetting = &iface,
  }
};
```

является синтаксически ошибочной в C++, так как в C++ не существуют именованные инициализаторы.

Кроме того, похоже в этом определении имеется опечатка. Должно быть

```
const struct usb_interface ifaces[] = {  
  {
    .num_altsetting = 1,
    .cur_altsetting = &iface,
//   ^^^^
  }
};
```

В С++ это определение могло бы выглядеть как

```
const usb_config_descriptor::usb_interface ifaces[] = 
{  
    { &iface, 1, }
};
```

Скорей всего вам этот модуль, где присутствует эта инициализация следует компилировать отдельно именно как C-модуль и его объектный код подключать к проекту на C++.